# What's the difference between modpolyfit and peak.Detection functions in R baseline package in terms of interpolation?

Tags: r, interpolation

I want to use these functions to subtract the baseline off the spectrum. The first one, the modpolyfit I guess just interpolates every nth point of the spectrum. But how about the baseline.peakDetection? Does it eliminates a local maximum or only use median or min points to do the interpolation? I hope that this won't be disregarded as a technical question, as I want to know the algorithm of each.

Comment: There are no functions by these names in `R`.  What package are you using?  What does its documentation say about the algorithms?  If this is the `baseline` package, note that the help page for `baseline.peakDetection` states "Peak detection is done in several steps sorting out real peaks through different criteria. Peaks are removed from spectra and minimums and medians are used to smooth the remaining parts of the
spectra."

Comment: @whuber I read the documentation, but was still not in the clear. Does it only remove the maximum of the peak or disregard all the points that lie in the peak area? Sorry, I am not an expert at this.